# Extension in App Manifest do not show tile

Tags: windows-phone-8, icons, manifest, tile

I've done an application! I've added some extension to app manifest

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="Camera_Capture_App" ConsumerID="{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5631}" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Now i go to camera, I click on "Filters" (i suppose it is "filters" in English) and then i see all application. But the strange thing is that I do not see the icon of my tile. I just can see an empty tile Blue (blue is the color of the theme of my phone).

It seems that image miss in app manifest, but in the manifest i've added all images:
- App Icon
- Small and Medium

I am using the Template Iconic so there is no Large Tile.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [the design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj662922%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which list all the icon sizes you need?

*The lens picker requires icons that are a different resolution than the icon that represents the app itself. Your app must provide three icons in the Assets folder, one for each of the possible phone resolutions. The following table describes the names and resolutions for each of these icons.*

**WVGA** 173 x 173 *Lens.Screen-WVGA.png*

**HD720p** 259 x 259 *Lens.Screen-720p.png*

**WXGA** 277 x 277 *Lens.Screen-WXGA.png*

Comment: Ohhh. Honestly I did not either know what "Lens" was... Thanx